# How can I speed up this query

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

```
select 
    k.*, 
    (select count(*) from kkutu_ko k2 where left(k2._id, 1) = right(k._id, 1)) as cnt
from kkutu_ko k 
WHERE 
    _id like 'a%'
AND
    type ~ '(^|,)(0|1|3|7|8|11|9|16|15|17|2|18|20|26|19|INJEONG)($|,)'
AND
    LENGTH(_id) > 1
    LIMIT 100;
```

431399 rows in kkutu_ko.

I think it's slow because of `count(*)` and `type ~ blabla`.

How can I optimize this query?

Comment: You really can't.  You are doing arcane string manipulations in SQL.  This suggests that you need an improvement to the data model.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that's deep

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes) and the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)